# estimate the flow in the graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given undirected graph, all edges have weight 1; N, M are about 10^6
I need to find whether the flow between source and sink is bigger than some value X. X is quite small.

Using bfs until the flow is equal to X gives O(M*X) this is too slow for me.

Is there any quicker method to estimate flow?

Comment: Using BFS does not always give correct result. See counterexample in [Shortest two disjoint paths between two specified vertices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11880738/1009831).

Comment: I mean Edmonds-Karp using bfs.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests that Karger's algorithm can find minimum cuts efficiently, would that do?

Comment: don't understand how Karger's algorithm can help here

Comment: @Herokiller, it gives you an upper bound on the capacity each time it is run. When it bundles up a set of arcs, just replace them by one arc with the sum of the capacities. When one arc remains, you have a bound on the capacity.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is basically maxflow, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem

and [Dinic's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinic%27s_algorithm) is recommended for practical efficient.

and in case you need some example, you may refer to one of my code, at http://wiki.attiix.com/index.php?title=Maxflow

Comment: as far as I understand Dinic's algorithm doesn't depend on the value of the flow, and O(VElogV) is too much

Comment: @Herokiller u a right, dinic doesn't concern the capacity of the edges, and i said it's practically efficient, O(VElogV) is the theoretic upper bound, which doesn't mean the actually run time, and dinic is every fast for leveled graphs, and for more general graphs, the only algo i know, which may be faster than dinic, is isap